# How to make a view that takes views from xml file

Tags: android, xml

I created a custom KeyboardView, I want the keyboard to take inputs from a xml file in the xml folder of android studio just like [the default keyboard view in android that is populated from a xml file (Row and Key)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java). I can create a layout file for the keyboard and it works fine but I think it will be easier to just edit a xml file to add or remove a key.

How the xml file looks like for the android keyboard

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="20%p"
    android:keyHeight="40dp"
    android:horizontalGap="5dp"
    android:verticalGap="5dp">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="0x0030" android:keyLabel="0" />
        <Key android:codes="0x0031" android:keyLabel="1" />
        <Key android:codes="0x0032" android:keyLabel="2" /> 
    </Row>
```

This is what I want to be able to do. I cant get the documentation to do this, maybe I am typing the wrong keywords.

I am reading the Keyboard.java code, but I don't totally understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The component responsible for parsing layout XML files is [`LayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater). The way layout inflater parses the XML file means that almost every tag in the XML needs to correspond to one view (an instance that extends the `View` class).

That means in your example, all `Keyboard`, `Row`, and `Key` needs to be custom views. By being in layout files, you are probably required to fully qualify the classnames of your custom views as well, so it will more likely become something like this:

```
    <com.example.Row>
        <com.example.Key android:codes="0x0030" android:keyLabel="0" />
        <com.example.Key android:codes="0x0031" android:keyLabel="1" />
        <com.example.Key android:codes="0x0032" android:keyLabel="2" /> 
    </com.example.Row>
```

Even then, that might not be what you want, because I suspect you want one custom view `KeyboardView`, and the tags inside are configurations that affects how `KeyboardView` behaves without adding child views.

`LayoutInflater` doesn't allow children tags to be used this way, so you have to find alternative ways to specify your value. One way to do that is to create an attribute that refers to a separate XML file:

```
<com.example.KeyboardView
  app:configuration="@xml/keyboard_layout" />
```

And then you can create `res/xml/keyboard_layout.xml` in a schema you define. You will need to write your own code for parsing the XML file, so you can define the XML schema however you like. For an example of how to achieve that, you can check out the [generic inflater](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/preference/GenericInflater.java) used to parse the `<Preference>` XMLs.

In fact, that's exactly what the `Keyboard` class you linked is doing. It's not a custom view (it doesn't extend `View` class), nor is it supposed to be included in layout XML files.

Comment: Having said all of that, if using XML to configure is not a requirement, I think you will have an easier time adding a `KeyboardView.setKeyboardLayout` method that takes a [Kotlin type-safe builder](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html) instead.